# Ограничение в массиве с++

Tags: c++

У меня есть программа  , она выводит неповторяющиеся числа ( после вашего ввода ) . Возможно очень глупый вопрос , но я не понимаю , как мне уменьшить возможный диапазон вводимых чисел . К примеру . чтобы в массиве были только положительные числа меньше 50. В противном случае они тоже выбрасываются. Сама программа. Пожалуйста , покажите , как это будет выглядеть в моем коде.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int non_repeating_elements(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j )
                break;
        }
        if (j == n )
        {
            cout <<" F " << arr[i] << endl;
            
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    int n=1, i;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of elements : ";
    cin >> n;

    int* arr = new int[n];
    cout << "\nInput the array elements : ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    non_repeating_elements(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нарируйте массив в виде клеточек. Занисите по одному числу в клеточки. Сделайте "кадры" как вы видете алгоритм. Потом "кадры" и "действия" перенесёте на язык алгоритмов.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь нарушить концепцию "статический массив", это делать можно, представьте что он псевдостатический, т.е. просто не до конца наполняете массив - так можно, не запрещено, или осваивайте "динамический массив".

Comment: Честно говоря , я думал , что работаю с динамическим массивом с самого начала. Насчет применения идеи о использовании "кадров" , я вроде бы пытался это сделать до этого , но получается ерунда( числа просто не сравниваются )

Comment: *`"как мне уменьшить возможный диапазон вводимых чисел . К примеру . чтобы в массиве были только положительные числа меньше 50"`* -- `arr[i] = abs(x % 50);`

Comment: @avp так это будет в ущерб данным. Я думал нужен "фильтр" (*выбрасывается* - наверно фильтр).

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну, если входящие данные нельзя менять (в вопросе про это ни слова), то очевидно, `if (x >= 0 && x < 50) ....`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int non_repeating_elements(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j )
                break;
        }
        if (j == n )
        {
        
            cout <<" F " << arr[i] << endl;
            
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    int n=1, i;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of elements : ";
    cin >> n;
 int lol =0;
 
    int* arr = new int[n];
    cout << "\nInput the array elements : ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> lol;
        if(lol<0 ||lol>50)
        cout << "error";
        else
         arr[i] = lol;
    }
    non_repeating_elements(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Всем спасибо , все оказалось очень просто.